# I've got int number and the functions must return double number

Tags: c++

i have a little problem  , i make all the variables double
then i still have result =  int number and i really don't know why
thx ♥

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
const double pi {3.14159} ;
calc_radius_circle( double radius){
    
    
    return pi * radius * radius ;
}
double area_circle() {
 double radius {};
    cout << "\n Enter the radius of circle " ;
    cin >> radius ;
    cout << "The area of circle with " << radius << " is " << calc_radius_circle(radius)  <<endl; 
}
int main () {
   area_circle();
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `calc_radius_circle` doesn't have a declared return type. You should have received a compiler error or at least a warning about it. Some compilers accept a function without return type and default to `int`, as an extension.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yeah exactly  the compiler  give me a warning   i forget to declare the function with double thx alot the problem soloved

Comment: @idclev463035818 g++ in  codelite IDE

Comment: codelite is not a compiler. Its an IDE that helps you to invoke a compiler

Comment: @idclev463035818 yeah sorry i edit my comment g++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need calc_radius_circle to return a double so your code should look like this.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
const double pi {3.14159} ;
double calc_radius_circle( double radius){
    
    
    return pi * radius * radius ;
}
double area_circle() {
 double radius {};
    cout << "\n Enter the radius of circle " ;
    cin >> radius ;
    cout << "The area of circle with " << radius << " is " << calc_radius_circle(radius)  <<endl; 
}
int main () {
   area_circle();
    return 0 ;
}
```